# numpy.where() with 3 or more conditions

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, where-clause

I have a dataframe with multiple columns.

```
      AC     BC     CC      DC     MyColumn
```

A

B

C

D

I would like to set a new column "MyColumn" where if BC, CC, and DC are less than AC, you take the max of the three for that row. If only CC and DC are less than AC, you take the max of CC and DC for that row, etc etc. If none of them are less than AC, MyColumn should just take the value from AC.

How would I do this with numpy.where()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is that you need the maximum of columns which are less than the first column,  with the fall-back on the first column if no such column exists; if that is the case:

```
>>> df
          A         B         C         D
0  1.587878 -2.189620  0.631958 -0.432253
1 -1.636721  0.568846 -0.033618 -0.648406
2  1.567512  1.089788  0.489559  1.673372
3  0.589222 -1.176961 -1.186171  0.249795
4  0.366227  1.830107 -1.074298 -1.882093

[5 rows x 4 columns]
>>> df[df.lt(df.A, axis=0)].max(axis=1).fillna(df.A)
0    0.631958
1   -1.636721
2    1.089788
3    0.249795
4   -1.074298
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Brilliant, this might sound really stupid but I never knew about the lt function (or the corresponding gt, le, ge, etc). Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 6):

You can use the lt method along with where:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
          A         B         C         D
0  1.587878 -2.189620  0.631958 -0.432253
1 -1.636721  0.568846 -0.033618 -0.648406
2  1.567512  1.089788  0.489559  1.673372
3  0.589222 -1.176961 -1.186171  0.249795
4  0.366227  1.830107 -1.074298 -1.882093
```

Note: you can take max of a subset of columns:

```
In [13]: df[['B', 'C', 'D']].max(1)
Out[13]:
0    0.631958
1    0.568846
2    1.673372
3    0.249795
4    1.830107
dtype: float64
```

Look at each column's values to see if they are less than A:

```
In [14]: lt_A = df.lt(df['A'], axis=0)

In [15]: lt_A
Out[15]:
       A      B      C      D
0  False   True   True   True
1  False  False  False  False
2  False   True   True  False
3  False   True   True   True
4  False  False   True   True

In [15]: lt_A[['B', 'C', 'D']].all(1)
Out[15]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Now, you can build up your desired result using all:

```
In [16]: df[['B', 'C', 'D']].max(1).where(lt_A[['B', 'C', 'D']].all(1), 2)
Out[16]:
0    0.631958
1    2.000000
2    2.000000
3    0.249795
4    2.000000
dtype: float64
```

Rather than 2 you can insert first the Series (in this example it happens to be the same):

```
In [17]: df[['C', 'D']].max(1).where(lt_A[['C', 'D']].all(1), 2)
Out[17]:
0    0.631958
1    2.000000
2    2.000000
3    0.249795
4   -1.074298
dtype: float64
```

and then column A:

```
In [18]: df[['B', 'C', 'D']].max(1).where(lt_A[['B', 'C', 'D']].all(1), df[['C', 'D']].max(1).where(lt_A[['C', 'D']].all(1), df['A']))
Out[18]:
0    0.631958
1   -1.636721
2    1.567512
3    0.249795
4   -1.074298
dtype: float64
```

*Clearly, you should write this as function if you're planning on reusing!*

Comment: Really great explanation. This would've been the perfect answer if the top answer wasn't slightly more efficient. Really explained how the other person got to his answer though and was super educational. Thank you!

Comment: @mit13plee however these answers do *slightly* different things!